# Weird behaviour of thread function when inserting an item to a CTreeCtrl

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I'm working on a IRC download client and downloads can be added by clicking a link, containing server address, port and all other information required to download a file from the irc. I'm saving this information into a file, to reload the download list when the user has quit and restarted the download client. When loading the download list, I'm running a `CWinThread` function for each download. The function creates a list (vector) of all server connections. If a connection to the appropriate server does not exist it adds a new one accordingly. Everything works as expected, but if I add an item to a `CTreeCtrl`, the program cycle seems to be way different.

```
//For each download I'm calling this in a loop
AfxBeginThread(RequestDownload, (LPVOID)&m_RequestStruct);

//In this function I'm comparing the available server 
//connections with the required server connection
//for the download and set a BOOL if it exists

UINT MyProgramDlg::RequestDownload(LPVOID pParam)
{
    //...
    if (ConnectionExists)
    {
        //Use the connection and 
        //don't add a new one to the list
    }

    if (!ConnectionExists)
    {
        //Add a new connection
        ConnectionStruct Connection;
        Connection.Status = STAT_DISCONNECTED;
        Connection.Connecting = FALSE;
        Connection.Connected = FALSE;
        Connection.LoggingOn = FALSE;
        Connection.LoggedOn = FALSE;
        Connection.Listening = FALSE;
        Connection.NetworkName = pRS->pm_Downloads->at(DownloadIndex).NetworkName;
        Connection.NetworkAddress = pRS->pm_Downloads->at(DownloadIndex).NetworkAddress;

        // Insert the tree item and save its handle
        // The following line is the EVIL LINE that makes my program misbehave
        Connection.hTreeItem = pRS->pm_TreeCtrl->InsertItem(_T("Test"), 0, 0, NULL, NULL);

        // Add the new connection
        pRS->pm_Connections->push_back(Connection);
        // (BREAK POINT 1)

        // Get the index of the added connection
        ConnectionIndex = (int) pRS->pm_Connections->size() - 1;
        // (BREAK POINT 2)
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

If I load two downloads from the same server address without(!) the "Evil Line", the debugger jumps from break point 1 to break point 2 and then again from break point 1 to break point 2. But with the evil line being enabled it jumps from break point 1 to break point 1 and then from break point 2 to break point 2.

I desperately need to fix this.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the `MyProgramDlg::RequestDownload` function a *static* member function? Because it needs to be. A non-static member function has a hidden argument that becomes the `this` variable. Such problems are usually solved by using `static` wrapper functions which as arguments takes a structure containing (a pointer to) the object, and then call the real function using that object.

Comment: Yeah, it is a static member function

Comment: So is this function is being run by more than one thread?  If so it sounds like you are context switching between threads in the debugger with each step instruction.  Visual Studio will do that if you have a breakpoint in such a function.  Bring up the thread window.  Start debugging.  Check to see if you are in a different thread when it jumps.

Workaround for this case is to right click on the thread you do NOT want to debug and choose "Suspend" (might be "Freeze", I forget) and then resume debugging.  Be sure to unfreeze it when you are done

Comment: Isn't [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) an instant messaging protocol? Downloading from IRC is something new to me.

Comment: @Joe Thanks! Looks like that's actually the case. I added a delay at the start of the function.

        Sleep(DownloadIndex * 100);

Which prevents two threads running at the same time. If someone has a better solution to this, please let me know. 

VTT IRC comes with a protocol called XDCC. It's very old but still powerful. Check the download search engine and program that I'm working on at xweasel.org

Comment: Glad it helped (how about some upvote love?) I should say that unless you've got dozens of these threads running, I think that suspending the threads manually from the thread window might work better.  Once that delay expires, the debugger will start jumping back again.   Regardless I hope that's debug-only code!

Answer (score 0):

Adding just a Sleep might not work! Try adding a thread synchronization method like a critical section or a Mutex.

Comment: I don't really know what a critical section or a mutex is. Can you give me further information about. Maybe even a code sample?

Comment: See this link for a simple Critical Section implementation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686908(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal for a worker thread to make **direct** calls to the UI, which explains the weird behavior. Pass a handle to the thread, then use sendMessage / postMessage.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you please give me an code example of how to do that?